# Nginx returns 404 on proxy_pass

Tags: nginx

I have the following configuration on Nginx 1.20.1, whenever I try to access test.xxx.com/something/ I get a 404 error. I know there are other similar questions but I already have the / at the end of the proxy_pass so I have no idea what to do. The strange thing is that I have 20 other servers on that configuration, they are all identical but only this one doesn't work. Any idea?

```
upstream test {
   server x.x.x.x:8443;
}
```

```
server {
    listen 8090;
    server_name test.xxx.com;
    root /var/www/vhosts/test.xxx.com/;
    location / {
        access_log /var/log/nginx/access_test.log upstreamlog;
        proxy_pass https://test/;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Scheme $scheme;
        proxy_connect_timeout 75s;
        proxy_send_timeout 1800s;
        proxy_read_timeout 1800s;
    }
}
```

Comment: What kind of application is listening behind the proxy?

Comment: There's an IIS with a simple web application, if I call that application directly (via IP), it works like a charm.

Comment: I usually set proxy_pass to a local address. The application behind should listen to an intern port. i.e. `proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:1234;`.

Answer (score 0):

It might not be the case for you, but when I ran into this, it turned out to be the upstream server that was returning 404, and nginx was reporting it correctly.

I increased the log level of the upstream server and debugged the issue there.